# COUNTIFS with greater than TODAY OR blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question regarding `COUNTIFS`. The simple boiled down version of what I am trying to do is this:

I am trying to use `COUNTIFS` to count the number of entries that the cell in a column is either blank or in the future (greater than today) and that is marked with an “X” in another column.

There are several other renditions in the formula but if I can get this, I can get the rest. So far, I have this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$50,{"";">"&TODAY()},$E$2:$E$50,"X"))
```

Excel won’t let me return out of the formula and highlights the quotation mark following the greater than symbol.

`=SUM(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$50,{"";">100"},$E$2:$E$50,"X"))` works fine when I play around and test things but when I try to add in `&TODAY()` or reference a cell, things go sideways.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? The actual formula is quite long and there are several comparisons that are made between columns.  I've seen some references to using `SUMPRODUCT` but haven't been able to figure it out that way either.

Comment: Add two separate COUNTIFS together.  That method only works as you found out with a range of cells or straight strings.  So do `=COUNTIFS(...) + COUNTIFS(...)`

Comment: Array constants cannot contain cell references, columns or rows of unequal length, formulas, or the special characters $ (dollar sign), parentheses, or % (percent sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula to generate the criteria array, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$50,IF({1;0},"",">"&TODAY()),$E$2:$E$50,"X"))`

I used `SUMPRODUCT` in this version because with `SUM` you'd need <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The `IF` function generates an array that resolves to something like this:

`{"";">43060"}`

Comment: This is opening too many possibilities...Between this and the INDEX() the other day.  I thought I knew formulas, but dang...

Comment: Just because I book marked this and wanted to keep this knowledge for myself:  Another version that would allow the growth to more than two: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$50,CHOOSE({1,2},"",">"&TODAY()),$E$2:$E$50,"X"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yep, I used `IF` because it's shorter and it works in this scenario but `CHOOSE` is clearly more flexible if you want to generate an array with more than 2 elements. This technique can also be used (both IF and CHOOSE) to create a multi-row array, e.g. `IF({1,0},B1:B10,A1:A10)` - would create a 10*2 array that effectively swaps `A1:A10` with `B1:B10`

Comment: @barry Houdini - Thank you for the formula, I think I will be able to incorporate this into my project and solve the problem.  Thanks everyone for their input, much appreciated.

Comment: One more question--Is it possible to add an additional IF  to the formula?  Something like:    =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$50,IF({1;0},"",">"&TODAY()),$E$2:$E$50,"X",$B$2:$B$50,IF({1;0},"","<"&TODAY())))

Comment: You can but you need to change the separator in {1;0} for one of them, so that you have one {1;0} and one {1,0} - that ensures any combination will be counted correctly. Two is the limit, if you need more then you need a different approach